# Failed to resolve: com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1251

Tags: android, adobecreativesdk

I'm having trouble Android Studio to find Adobe Creative SDK.

I have downloaded sample from [github](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/android-getting-started-samples).

I have set my Key class as per instruction.

My gradle file of application.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.adobe.imageeditorui"
        minSdkVersion 16 // Minimum is 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        manifestPlaceholders = [appPackageName: "${applicationId}"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    /* 2) Compile for Java 1.8 or greater */
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    /* 3) Exclude duplicate licenses */
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        pickFirst 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

    /* 4) Enable jumbo mode */
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1251'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.8.4'
    compile "com.localytics.android:library:3.8.0"
}
```

and main gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        /* 1) Add the Gradle Retrolambda Plugin */
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.0-beta4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        /* 2) Add mavenCentral */
        mavenCentral()

        /* 3) Add the Creative SDK Maven repo URL */
        maven {
            url 'https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/'
        }

        maven {
            url 'http://maven.localytics.com/public'
        }


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

But still i am having issue while sync project below :

**--> Failed to resolve: com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1251**

**--> Failed to resolve: com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.8.4**

Comment: did you find any solution please help me

Comment: add dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }

Comment: did u find solution?

Comment: Didn't find any solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use aar library download ***com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1251*** from above link

[Link](https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/com/adobe/creativesdk/foundation/auth/0.9.1251/auth-0.9.1251.aar)

then place it to library folder and import it.

and for another library download it from above link and do same again.

[Link](https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/com/adobe/creativesdk/image/4.8.3/image-4.8.3.aar)

Hope it help.

Comment: Thanx @Mohmmad for your answer, still i have facing problem while sync project like 
-> Error:(1518, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'adobe_fontFamily'.
-> Error:(1950, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'ttlm_arrowRatio'. ETC

Comment: @JaydeepGadhia have you found solution for this ?

Comment: @Mohamamad I still facign ussue with style.xml

Comment: @Mohammad please help me I facing issue with adobe_fontFamily

Comment: @PriyankaChauhan No i can't find any solution for that uptill

Comment: @JaydeepGadhia My issue solved. please check your gardle version

Answer (score 2):

In your main application, *gradle* file add this:

```
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/'
    }

    maven {
        url 'http://maven.localytics.com/public'
    }

    maven{
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }

    mavenCentral()
}
```

You have two repositories of maven already included. Add the google maven repo as well. This will solve the problem.